# some Google calendar frames not visible in tabs

Tags: iframe, browser, tabs, calendar

This is so weird. I'm having trouble embedding multiple Google calendars into a website when using a tabbed interface. What happens is the default calendar (on the first tab) is always visible just fine, and any others are collapsed.

Looking at the DOM tree tells me that the content is loading fine, it's just not visible.

Also it depends on the browser. All calendars display fine on my iPhone (Safari), but the problem above occurs on Safari on my laptop as well as IE and Chrome on my desktop.

Please see a demonstration of the problem here:

http://noeltaylor.com/calendar_weirdness.html

The two iframes have slightly different src attributes, but that is not the issue because a) all content is downloading, just not displaying and b) if I switch the order of the calendars, the one that is not displaying now will display, and vice-versa.

The page above uses jQuery-UI for the tabs; I even tried using a different library for the tabs and the results were exactly the same!

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has something to do with the iframes not being completely loaded onto the page before making the jquery ui tabs call.

I found the following approach where you do not load the iframe until the tab is selected to work very nicely

http://deano.me/2011/08/jquery-tabs-iframes/